# Add a caret on top of a string in HTML?

Tags: html

Is there any way for me to put a caret on top of a string of characters in HTML? In LaTeX, I would do this:

```
\hat{mystring}
```

How can I get the same effect in HTML?

Comment: Some users here might not know what the output of LaTeX's `\hat` looks like. Perhaps you could provide an image of the output to make it clear what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p>&#94;string</p>
```

Comment: That puts the caret to the left. I need it on top of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate it using the `::before` pseudo-element.

You may need to adjust the left `calc` based on your font size:

```css
.hat {
  position: relative;
  font: 16px verdana;
}

.hat::before {
  content: "^";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 70%;
  top: -20%;
  left: calc(50% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<span class="hat">a</span>
<span class="hat">e</span>
<span class="hat">i</span>
<span class="hat">o</span>
<span class="hat">u</span>
<br><br>
<span class="hat">string</span>
```